# How can i switch first tab to another tab in my signup form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched and find some resource in stackoverflow but those are working for me.I can not switch from first tab to another tab? Can anyone tell me where is the problem in my code?

You can see code in **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yxvyLdqy/)**

This is my all file respectively **custom.js** , **style.css** and **index.html** file.

Thanks in advanced.

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}
body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <!-- multistep form -->
      <form id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
          <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
          <li>Social Profiles</li>
          <li>Personal Details</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
          <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
          <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
          <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
          <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
          <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
          <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
          <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
          <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
          <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
          <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I can not switch` Do you mean that in the default the `another tab` (Which tab?) will shown or to let the user to swich the tabs?

Comment: when I fill up first form and click next then it automatically goes to second tab/form.

Comment: So, What's the problem?

Comment: @MoshFeu I understand my problem.I did not add `js` file for that's why its not changing.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: so is it solved? please delete the question then

Comment: @Gavriel Yes, Solved.please tell me, Have any problem if i do not delete this?

Comment: at least close it or write an answer and accept it or something so other people don't waste their time on reading it trying to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `script` file.Add js file in markup.Just include `jquery.js` and `easing.min.js`. It will work fine.